# Record a video via a usb WebCam in csharp

Tags: c#, webcam

I have a simple use case. Where I want to display a usb webcam and record the the live video(Not as screen capture). 
I have checked these links

1) [WebCam](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/125478/Versatile-WebCam-C-library)

2)[Simple Webcam](http://easywebcam.codeplex.com/)

But it does not show how to record a video. Can I extend these to record a video or should I look at some other dll ?

Edit: Currently I am using Expression encoder SDK, but is giving a issue with a specific use case ([Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18043543/how-to-detect-a-event-on-a-wrapped-object-in-c-sharp))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Video capture APIs in Windows are:

1. Video for Windows (simple, limited, deprecated, really outdated)
2. DirectShow
3. Media Foundation

All three are native APIs, so you need wrappers to interface from managed code. #3 is supposed to be a successor to #2 but reality makes #2 still the best - in general terms - API for video capture out there. In particular, Expression Encoder uses DirectShow.

DirectShow.NET lets you do DirectShow from C#, and it has [`CapWMV` Sample](http://sourceforge.net/projects/directshownet/files/) for you:

> Capture from video capture devices to WMV files.

[`MFCaptureToFile` Sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663604%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) shows you ho to achieve video capture via Media Foundation:

> Shows how to capture video from a video camera to a file.